# Need help in posting data to MySQL using PHP from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am developing a sample android app which has two EditTexts and a 'Save' button.
It gets data from EditTexts and posts it to MySQL server using PHP. The code is blow.

My onClick method to save data

```
 public void saveMy(View v)
{
    name=e1.getText().toString();
    no=e2.getText().toString();
    try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/GujaratiApp/myPHP.php");


            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",name));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("No",no));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+ex.toString());
    }  


}
```

The PHP code is:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("newDB");
$name =   $_POST['Name'];
$no = $_POST['No'] ;

$query_add="INSERT INTO  myData (`name` ,`no` ) VALUES ('.$name','.$no')";


$query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 


mysql_close();
```

?>

When I click the Save button there is a message in LogCat that HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
And when I fire query in MySQL monitor it adds one row to the table but the added row doesn't show anything.
See image below:[image]

I don't know what is going wrong.. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont u put an echo statement in PHP to see if the data received by PHP actually matches what you sent. At least you can isolate where the problem is

Comment: Why do people build new applications with `mysql_query`? It's dangerous, it's deprecated, and `mysqli` and PDO are way better. If `$name` contains anything nasty, your whole database could be deleted. You cannot write PHP code like this and expect it will work. What if `Martin O'Malley` signs up? Your app dies. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you will sleep better at night.

Answer (score 0):

Please add null check on the columns in mySQL, making the fields mandatory.

```
ALTER TABLE myData Modify name varchar(xyz) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE myData Modify no varchar(abc) NOT NULL;
```

After that please check if you are getting response status 200. This will verify if the post parameters are received correctly on the service.
If not then you may try to pass these parameters through URL itself by appending it to the url.

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/GujaratiApp/myPHP.php?name=" + name + "&no=" + no);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

That should get you going if

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters)
```

is not working.

Comment: I am getting this in my LogCat:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK... And my table has already NOT NULL attributes..

Comment: I do not have an idea about how does php translates unparsed or unavailable parameters. But, android does have issues with `UrlEncodedFormEntity` and a lot of people face it regularly. You can however try to use parameters with URL. That will help.

Comment: I am no good with PHP. But the code seems ok. Only possibility is that you parameters are not reaching your php. Although I agree with what Tadman said above.

Comment: I did some modifications in my Java code and yes it is working.. You can see them in my java code.